# photoshop script adding options to panel

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I've got the following code:

```
obj = w.add('panel', [45,50,350,135], 'Title'),
```

How do I add options, such as `size`, `margins`, `alignChildren` to this panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional settings after the object is created.  Pretty sure there is a syntax to add the additional criteria in the 'add' method as well, but I never use it - I find below easier to read...

```
    win.grpSpacing = win.pnlGeneral.add("group",undefined);
    win.grpSpacing.alignChildren = "fill";
```